# How can I quickly dump a query result set into JSON?

Tags: javascript, python, django, json

```
import simplejson as json
results = Content.objects.filter(blah)
theresult_json = json.dumps(results)
```

This doesn't work!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/

?

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize('json', SomeModel.objects.all())

# it's pretty useful and quick.
data = serializers.serialize('json', SomeModel.objects.all(), fields=('foo','bar'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`results` is a python object. `simplejson.dumps` only works on python dict's/list's.

You need to convert your results object to a dict first. Either you do it manually like this:

```
l = [] 

for result in results:
    d = {
        'attr1': result.attr1,
        'attr2': result.attr2,
        ...
    }
    l.append(d)

theresult_json = simplejson.dumps(l)
```

or dynamically with a the objects `__dict__` method, removing non JSON serializable attributes from it afterwards:

```
l = [] 

for result in results:
    d = result.__dict__
    # remove attributes from dict which are not JSON-serializable with del d[key]
    l.append(d)

theresult_json = simplejson.dumps(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may also want to check out [Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home).  It has special Emitter classes for dumping your objects into a JSON format, XML format, etc... if you are building AJAX or API endpoints, the piston framework is incredibly useful.